# Marvell 91xx SATA 6G Controller "An I/O adapter hardware error has occurred"

Tags: drivers, sata

I ma having a problem with a device in Windows 10. I can install it fine (it seems) but now I can not get it to start. I am getting an error in properties

```
This device cannot start. (Code 10)
An I/O adapter hardware error has occurred.
```

I think the driver is fine I have tried a ton of methods to install new drivers, but can not get past this error?

Q1: Dose anyone know where I can get working drivers for this card? 
Q2: If there is some other conflict other than a bad driver, then how can I fix the "An I/O adapter hardware error has occurred" problem?

Thanks!

Comment: The fact the device is unable to start indicates a driver problem.  You have installed drivers that specifically supports Windows 10? You provided zero information about your motherboard.

Comment: how do you find out what your mother board is? There are no official windows 10 drivers I think.. I followed a number of solutions found on google but they all seam to stop at getting the thing to show in device manager. I have that, ity is just not "working" due to this I/O error.. but I can not find out how to fix it.